# Slowly decreasing validation / training cost and their abnormal values

Tags: regression, cnn, hyperparameter, learning-rate

I have a dataset of size ~100,000 of images, I'm training a CNN model on them for regression.

- optimizer: `Adam`
- batch_size: 64
- Number of epochs: 50

When I set the learning rate for `Adam` optimizer for $1e-2$ and $1e-3$, training and validation costs were normal and soon converged to good and predictable values. But now I've set the `lr` for $1e-1$ to just test it but training and validation costs are strange values, first $80k$ ! and after many `epochs` now they are reached to $600$. What's wrong with my `hyperparameters`, etc?

What about the `decay` in this situation? what should it be? its current value is $\frac{1e-1}{80}$

I really appreciate any help.